# displaying single object list in two different listbox through Silverlight MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding, mvvm, observablecollection

I am creating an application for Windows Phone. I am using Panorama view for the main page. The panorama view contains two panorama items each consist of a listbox tied to a datasource (i.e. in-memory collection using ObservableCollection). The object has 2 boolean properties `IsA` and `IsB`.

I want to display the object's string data in two list, but the data is differentiated by the boolean variable. That is, if `IsA` is set `true` then object must be displayed in list box of panaroma item 1 and if `IsB` is `true` then it must be displayed in list box of panaroma item 2.

But i have only one list of objects as described aboove. I tried different binding expressions in xaml while binding listboxitem but none helped me.

Please help with this. As this is really getting on my nerves.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanx for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ItemTemplate` to define how items are displayed in a `ListBox`. You could define one template for each `ListBox` and bind the boolean properties to the `Visibility` of the item. That would show only the items for which the property is set.

Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms742521.aspx#DataTemplating_Basic).